# Fire event when user stops to click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm able to detect a click on a button using jQuery

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
  // do something
});
```

but, when the user clicks many times on the button, it fires unnecessary intermediaries events.

I would like to fire the event only on the last click on the button.

Something like:

```
$('#myButton').lastClickOnASequenceOfClicks(function(){
  // ignore the multiple clicks followed
  // do something only on the last click of a sequence of clicks
});
```

With that, if the user clicks 10 times (with a little interval of time), it should fires an event only on the tenth click.

Comment: SetTimeout on the clicks?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Do you mean 'save' the time of the last click and compare? I thought it, but how can I know if I'm on the last click? It would be necessary stop to click, wait, and click again...

Comment: If you want to fire the event on only the *last* click you will always have to wait a little time to see if another click is made. Why not fire on the *first* click and then disable the button for some duration?

Comment: @76484 For example, if I have a list of products and the button loads the next product on a div. Then, if the user clicks many times quickly, load each product or block the button will poorer the user's experience... There are several situations like that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each click resets the timer.

```
var timer;

$("#myButton").click(function () {
    var timeToWait = 1000;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        // do something only on the last click
    }, timeToWait);
}
```

**Update**

Another way to solve this problem of handling 'multiple click events' generated by the user is to do what was mentioned in the OP comments section. `do something` on the first click THEN disable the button so the user cannot click it anymore (maybe also set a time for the button to become enabled again)

```
var timer, timeToWait = 5000, selector ="#myButton";

$(selector).click(function (e) {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    // do something
    // Then wait a certain amount of time then remove the disabled attr on your button
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $(selector).removeAttr("disabled");
    }, timeToWait);
})
```

Comment: this will not work, as you are declaring a new timer variable on each click. "var timer" should be moved outside of the click event handler!

Comment: Good catch. I was looking at it and something seemed wrong lol.